# Find a non-convex instance for a non-convex set function with FindInstance

Tags: findinstance

Let $f$ be a non-convex set function defined on a set $L$.
Hence there are subsets $A,B\subseteq L$ such that
$$f(A)+f(B)>f(A\cup B)+f(A\cap B).$$

I tried to use **FindInstance** function to find a non-convex instance of $x$ and $y$ as follows:

```
Powerset=Subsets[L];
FindInstance[f[x]+f[y]>f[Union[x,y]]+f[Intersection[x,y]],Powerset]
```

But I have the following errors:

```
Union::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in x\[Union]y.
Intersection::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in x\[Intersection]y.
FindInstance::ivar: {} is not a valid variable.
```

Does **FindInstance** work with set functions?
How should I modify my code?

Comment: _Does FindInstance work with set functions?_ No it doesn't. You could express your sets as fixed length binary vectors, then the union corresponds to a `BitOr` and the intersection corresponds to a `BitAnd`. You should provide the `f` you're using and an example set as this will help get an answer.

Comment: @flinty Thank you very much for your explanations and solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findit[L_, f_] :=
 (* select pairs of subsets in the powerset Subsets[L] that satisfy the criterion *)
 ResourceFunction["SelectSubsets"][
  Subsets[L], {2}, 
  Total[f /@ #] > f[Union @@ #] + f[Intersection @@ #] &
  ]
findit[{1, 2, 3}, Median]
(* result: {{{1,2},{1,3}}} *)

(* check it works *)
Median[{1, 2}] + Median[{1, 3}] > 
 Median[Union[{1, 2}, {1, 3}]] + Median[Intersection[{1, 2}, {1, 3}]]
(* result: True *)
```